# Get Current Date in 2017-10-30T03:00:00.852Z format Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I need to get current data in this format **2017-10-30T03:00:00.852Z** in JavaScript
does anyone knows how to do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the name of that format?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: @LambdaNinja [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Thank you for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use convert to the required format like this

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toISOString());
```

Comment: I don't understand what your second code snippet is meant to show. All that does is produce a `Date` instance ~4 days in the future

Comment: also can be converted like this date.toJSON()

Comment: @Phil thanks for correcting. I have updated the comment. It was meant to be something other.

Comment: Thank you very much for help